# Replace character from string if only previous or next character not containing the same character

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I have a set of string like this:

```
$string1 = 'man_city/man_united'; //it will  be replaced
$string2 = 'liverpool///arsenal'; //it will not be replaced
$string3 = 'chelsea//spurs'; //it will  not be replaced
$string4 = 'leicester/sunderland'; //it will be replaced
```

i want to replace the '/' character from string with '/' but only if next or previous character from '/' character not containing '/' too.

if i use str_replace like this, it won't work:

```
$name1 = str_replace("/","\/",$string1);
$name2 = str_replace("/","\/",$string2);
...
//output
$name1 = 'man_city\/man_united';
$name2 = 'liverpool\/\/\/arsenal';
...
//desired output
$name1 = 'man_city\/man_united';
$name2 = 'liverpool///arsenal';
...
```

Comment: Put the example of desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?<!/)/(?!/)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gowuHO/1).

The `(?<!/)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if there is a `/` before `/` and `(?!/)` negative lookahead will fail the match if there is a `/` after `/`.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ilKrLj):

```
$re = '~(?<!/)/(?!/)~';
$str = "man_city/man_united\nliverpool///arsenal\nchelsea//spurs\nleicester/sunderland";
$result = preg_replace($re, "\\/", $str);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
man_city\/man_united
liverpool///arsenal
chelsea//spurs
leicester\/sunderland
```

Comment: @nortonuser Basically, ``\`` in the replacement pattern is a special char, and a literal ``\`` should be defined with double literal ``\``. But since `/` is not making the escape special, just double ``\`` will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's easier to use a regular expression (=> `preg_replace()`).

e.g. `preg_replace(#/+#, '/', $str)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with negative lookarounds:

```
$name = preg_replace("/(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/","\/",$string1);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/12qWsC/1)

Explanation:

```
(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)
```

- `(?<!\/)` negative lookbehind - matches a place in the string that is nontpreceded with `/`
- `\/` matches '/'
- `(?!\/)` negative lookahead - matches place in the string not followed by `/` 
  `

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this can help you:

```
<?php
$string1 = 'man_city/man_united'; //it will  be replaced

if(!substr_count($string1, '//')){
   $string1 = str_replace('/','#',$string1); //Do replace accordingly 
}

echo $string1;
```